# wkhtmltopdf page-break-after have whitespace

Tags: html, css, printing, wkhtmltopdf

I use `WKHTMLTOPDF` to generate a *PDF* from a printer-friendly webpage.
I upgraded from version **0.10.0 rc2** to **0.12.1***(with patched qt)* but now when I use the `CSS` properties like `page-break-before:always;` it inserts a bunch of *whitespace*, and the `page-breake-inside:avoid;` doesn't work, it's magic.

I use this call:

```
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf --encoding 'UTF-8' 'page-to-print' '/tmp/PDFV59OZt'
```

I have tried with and without both `--print-media-type` and `--no-print-media-type`.

When I render the printer-friendly page in my browser, and when I try to print it (before I make it a pdf) it works fine.

examples of my CSS:

```
//if i want to make a static page-break between two elements
page-break{
    page-break-after:always;
    clear:both;
    display:block;
}
//Avoid cutting images
img{
    display:block;
    page-break-before:auto;
    page-break-after:auto;
    page-break-inside:avoid;
}
//avoid cutting text
p,em,li,span,tr{ 
    page-break-inside:avoid; 
}
```

Only page-break-after:always; works, but it inserts a bunch of white-space.
Does anyone have any ideas for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution i found was to set the page size to A3, which make all the clever printerfriendly stuff work.

I use this WKHTMLTOPDF call:

```
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf --page-size 'A3' --encoding 'UTF-8' '<LINK TO PAGE>' '/tmp/PDFX6BefV'
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using version wkhtmltopdf 0.12.0

For me, page breaks ONLY work with --print-media-type.
Without it, page break protection for images works, but not page-break-after or before.

I had to make a special css file for print media to get it work.

Setting the paper size to 'A3' or using the 'overflow: visible' didn't make any difference.

Also see [WKHTMLTOPDF with pdfkit on Rails ignoring table page breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27193481/wkhtmltopdf-with-pdfkit-on-rails-ignoring-table-page-breaks)