# wkhtmltopdf page-break-before div have whitespace in new page, div not shown

Tags: html, whitespace, wkhtmltopdf, page-break

I am generating a PDF with wkhtmltopdf from a generated html-file.
I use the latest wkhtmltopdf version (0.12.2.0) for *windows*.

My additional wkhtmltopdf parameters are:

```
--zoom 1.0
--encoding "UTF-8"
--page-offset -1
--footer-html "C:\tmp\footer.html"
--header-html "C:\tmp\header.html"
--header-spacing 10
--footer-spacing 10 toc
--xsl-style-sheet "C:\tmp\toc.xsl"
```

In the *footer.html, header.html, toc.xsl* are nothing defined about page-breaks.
The HTML is valid. Every tag which is opened is closed in the right order. I've checked it twice.

If I insert a page-break-**after** div all works fine. But I need a page-break-**before** too. If I insert a page-break-**before** div it breaks the page too, but on the new page there is a block of white space and the div is not shown.

```
<div style='page-break-before: always; height: 10px; width: 100%; background-color: red;'>
 <span style='color:rgb(0, 0, 0)'>OOO</span>
</div>
```

It doesn't matter if this style properties are set or not: "height: 10px; width: 100%;"

The two pages should look like:

```
+--------------------+
|                  1 |
|   xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   |
|   xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   |
|   xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   |
|   xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   |
|   xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   |
|   xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   |
|   xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   |
|   xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
+--------------------+
-
+--------------------+
|                  2 |
|   OOOOOOOOOOOOOO   |
|   xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   |
|   xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   |
|   xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   |
|   xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   |
|   xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   |
|   xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
+--------------------+
```

But they look like (div not shown and a large whitespace on next page):

```
+--------------------+
|                  1 |
|   xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   |
|   xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   |
|   xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   |
|   xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   |
|   xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   |
|   xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   |
|   xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   |
|   xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
+--------------------+
-
+--------------------+
|                  2 |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|   xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   |
|   xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   |
|   xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   |
|   xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   |
|   xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   |
|   xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   |
|                    |
+--------------------+
```

The x-es are the placeholders for the text. The O-s are the placeholder for my div.

I've already tried this from answer 1. [wkhtmltopdf page-break-after have whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27058472/wkhtmltopdf-page-break-after-have-whitespace) The whitespace is already there.

---

**Update:**

In some other of my generated PDFs there are some texts over the other. I don't know why wkhtmltopdf does sometimes some whitespace and sometimes it puts one text over the other but if I set the css attribute:

```
overflow-x: visible !important;
```

in my CSS file. Then in the PDF there is no more senseless whitespace and there is no more one text over the other, but then it makes *no more page-breaks*.

---

**Solution:**

The main problem was, that the html I received from an other tool to put it in the wkhtmltopdf-tool was so complex with many div blocks and useless html-tags, that the wkhtmltopdf-tool made this error. With a cleaned html it works perfect.

Answer (score 2):

After hours of trying to fix a similar problem, I have found that the solution is to put the pages **immediately** in the body

```
<body>
<div style="page-break-inside: avoid;"> Here goes my page </div>
<div style="page-break-inside: avoid;"> Here goes my another page </div>
....
</body>
```

Another caveat is that if the content is larger than the page - the resulting PDF breaks. It is like with the cats - "if it fits - it sits" :)

Try to move content between pages to see if it fits.

Answer (score 0):

try to define page size(A4, A3, Letter) and this library also have its own margins. So you should set it to `0`.

http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt

And please provide your html example via jsfiddle for example.

Comment: That does not work. I tried it already (see my question last line).

Comment: Setting the margins to 0 has no effect to the whitespace. (see my question) I wrote that I checked the HTML via an HTML validator.